# Is it valid to quantify two variables over the same universe using the same quantifier (like in $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R} \:\: P(a,b)$)?

Tags: logic, notation, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am wondering if we can quantify two variables over the same universe using the same quantifier, such as in $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}\:\: P(a,b).$

Are statements like this found in mathematical expressions? If so, do we regard this as quantifying a tuple of elements or two individual elements?

Comment: These are ubiquitous in practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are equivalent to one another

- $\forall a\,\forall b \; \big(a\in \mathbb{R} \land b\in \mathbb{R}\implies P(a,b)\big)$
- $\forall a\,\forall b \; \big((a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2\implies P(a,b)\big)$
- $\forall (a,b) \; \big(a\in \mathbb{R} \land b\in \mathbb{R}\implies P(a,b)\big)$
- $\forall (a,b) \; \big((a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2\implies P(a,b)\big),$

while these are interchangeable abbreviations of the above

- $\forall a{,}b {\in} \mathbb{R}\:\: P(a,b)$
- $\forall a{\in} \mathbb{R}\:\forall b {\in} \mathbb{R}\:\: P(a,b)$
- $\forall (a,b) {\in} \mathbb{R}^2\:\: P(a,b).$

---

**Addendum**

[The StackExchange Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4640548/21813)

> is there a way to prove that $$∀,\;(∀\:(≥⟹≥)⟹≥)\;?$$

suggests two other abbreviations:

- $\forall a,b \; \big(a\in \mathbb{R} \land b\in \mathbb{R}\implies P(a,b)\big)$
- $\forall a,b \; \big((a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2\implies P(a,b)\big).$

Comment: Would you like to cite actual textbook examples where the likes of $\forall(a, b)$ are used? I can’t recall ever seeing that sort of usage out in the wild …

Comment: @PeterSmith: the notation $\forall(a,b)\dots$ is commonly supported in proof assistants like those in the HOL family. For the logical quantifiers, this doesn't add much value, but these systems also support the notation $\lambda(a, b)\dots$, which is really useful.

Comment: @PeterSmith Actually, me neither; I'd merely reverse-engineered it from that last bullet; thanks Rob for supplying the example. To be clear, all the above bullets are examples of informal writing (for example, mathematics) rather than formal logic.